# Insert multiple values from checkbox array with comma separated

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, insert

Here is my existing code i have
my db looks like this

```
req table
test_id(auto increment)    test_work varchar(50)

<?php
include_once '../connect.php'; //database connection
if($_COOKIE["Utype"]!="Logistic")
{
                header("Location: login.php");
}

if(!isset($_POST['mat']))
{
     $checkboxValue = false;
} else {
     $checkboxValue = $_POST['mat'];
}

$values = implode(",", $_POST["mat"]);

$sql="Insert into req(test_work)
values ('$values')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>


<script>
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('mat[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            $(this).next().val(1);
        } else {
            $(this).next().val(0);
        }
});

</script>
<form name="form" action="test.php" method="post">
<table border="1" width="200px" style="position:relative;top:0px;font-family:tahoma;font-size:12px;border-collapse:collapse">

<tr style="background-color:#f3f3f3">
<th width="2%"></th>
<th height="20px" width="15%">Work Order ID</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$resource=mysql_query("Select * from test",$con);

while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
    { 
    ?>
<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="mat[]" id="mat" value="<?php  echo $result2["id"]; ?>"/><?php  echo $result2["id"]; ?></td>
<td><?php  echo $result2["name"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php };?>
</table>
<input style="color:#FFFFFF;position:relative;width:70px"type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="imgClass" height="50px">
</form>
```

This can insert only one checked checkbox. but if i check multiple checkboxes it only inserts one value.

How can I do single and also multiple(with comma separated) inserts?
Like

as if i selected four checkbox from the array

```
 req table
    test_id(auto increment)    test_work varchar(50)
    23                         1, 2, 3, 4
```

and it omits the comma when i only select one checkbox

```
 req table
        test_id(auto increment)    test_work varchar(50)
        23                         1
```

Comment: code looks good did u try echo $sql; and see how it looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

So instead of inserting one record into req, with a value for test_work of 'val1,val2,val3', you want it to insert three records with values of 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', right?

In that case, try this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['mat']))
{
    $checkboxValue = false;
} else {
    $checkboxValue = $_POST['mat'];
    foreach($_POST['mat'] as $val)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO req (test_work) VALUES ('$val')";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your update still doesn't make it clear.  In the code you are inserting data into a column called test_work, but your update calls the column mat_id.

Comment: No, i needed it with comma separated.

Comment: You need what column comma separated?  mat_id, or test_work?  Also, what is the data type of the column and it's size?

Comment: Ok - I think I understand what you need now.  What is the data type and size of the test_work column?

Comment: hello sir rob?.. still there?

Comment: I'd just start debugging your post var and sql statement then.  Try a print_r($_POST['mat']) and see what it returns.  And echo out the sql before you run mysql_query on it.  Post results if you still need help.

Comment: these are the results sir in printing the values i selected..
'Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )'
the array values are good. the problem now is how to insert it in one column with comma separated? does implode will work here sir?

Comment: Yes, your implode should work fine.  Try echoing the results of implode: {echo $values;} and see what you get.  Also, echo the query {echo $sql} before running mysql_query on it.

Comment: Sir I can't make it... it's hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Your code will take multiple checkboxes and produce a string like: 1,2,5.

This will insert one row into your database where the "test_work" column has the value 1,2,5.